# Is the #disabled form element property different from the html disabled attribute?

Tags: forms

Looking at the [documentation for `#disabled`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#disabled) in the form API documentation, one finds this:

> Setting #disabled to TRUE results in user input being ignored,
>   regardless of how the element is themed or whether JavaScript is used
>   to change the control's attributes.

If I'm reading this correctly, this seems to indicate that this is different from the HTML `disabled` property.

If I want to make an element disabled, to later enable it via javascript, and have its value come through in `$form_state['values']`, I should not use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's different, as well as rendering the attribute the form API also ensures server-side validation is taken care of.

As with all Drupal form manipulation, the right way to remove the disabled attribute is with the [Ajax API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7), not by manipulating the input directly with JavaScript.

Once you use that method, you'll be able to get values for the input(s) in the form state as normal.

Comment: Say I have checkboxes that toggle different sets of inputs. The Drupal Way would be to trigger the ajax callback on those elements?

Comment: Correct, as the docs say: _As a developer you don't use or touch any JavaScript to create an Ajax-enabled form. Drupal does all the work for you._ You only need to write php for what you want, and the form API should have you covered for most eventualities

Comment: I don't want an ajax enabled form. I just want a checkbox to toggle a set of fields. I don't want Drupal doing four form submits, each with a `drupal_bootstrap`, just to enable four text fields.

Comment: If you want to change a sensitive attribute on a form built with the form API, it can only be done via Ajax. It's just how the thing was built

Comment: So there's no getting around a full bootstrap to enable a field?

Comment: There's no way to change the disabled status of an input field without informing the server that it's changed, for validation purposes. There's no way to do that without AJAX. A bootstrap is inevitable for such a request, so yes, what you say is accurate

Comment: Have you tried setting the HTML attribute only btw? `$form['foo']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';`? Not sure if Drupal validates that

Comment: Yes, it seems not to be being processed/applied. I was hoping to get clarification in the documentation : P

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in a situation similar to mine, the [`#states` FAPI key](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#states) can do a lot of what you want, without AJAX callbacks.

Any form element that is disabled in JavaScript should be validated by the back end

Comment: You should mention in your answer that any form element that is disabled in JavaScript should be validated by the back end.